# Expected Expression before Function Type in Main

Tags: c, function

I'm getting an error on line 34 saying there's an "expected expression before 'void'" (or int, if I change the function type, I'm not sure which it should be). I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Declare Function Prototypes
void PlayingDice(void);
void GuessNumber(void);

int main (void)
{
    // Loop so games can be replayed
    do
    {

        // Introducing Games
        int game, UserGuessDice, UserGuessNumber, die1, die2, sum, number;
        printf("Do you want to (1) play dice, (2) guess the number, or (3) exit program?\n");
        scanf("%d", &game);

        printf("You have selected %d.\n", game);

        if (game==1)
            {
                // Calls Playing Dice Game
                printf("%d", void PlayingDice(void));
            }

        else if (game==2)
            {
                // Calls Guess Number Game
                printf("%d", void GuessNumber(void));
            }

        else
            {
                // In case user enters invalid option
                printf("That wasn't an option!\n");
            }
    }

    while (game != 3);

    // End Program
    printf("Good bye.\n");

return (0);
}
```

Comment: How about a semicolon after `printf("Good bye.\n")`? Also `return main();` does not return your function *to* `main`, but rather calls `main()` (which is not allowed) and returns its value.

Comment: How about pressing TAB a few times where it's appropriate?

Comment: @Kninnug and after `printf("You chose %d.\n", UserGuessDice)`...

Comment: @OP: you should clearly **learn the language to a basic extent at least.** Elementary syntax errors are not quite appropriate questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If only compilers were able to check for such trivial errors and print some sort of message...

Comment: @Kninnug Oh thanks, I missed that. Still getting the same error, though.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I copy pasted and it didn't turn out well. I can go back and edit them in if it works better.

Comment: When you report an error, tell us which line it occurs at. Also try to cut the code down to a bare minimum.

Comment: @Kninnug All my compiler is saying is that there's an "expected expression before void" and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Line 34 ...

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand I had a couple silly errors missing the semicolons after printf, I'm just looking for some help in my university course so I'm half a semester into learning C.

Comment: @Kninnug That's what I thought for return main(); but my friend insisted when I was trying to get him to help me fix this error. I'll switch it back to what I had.

Comment: Not in comments, and don't expect us to count 34 lines. Mark it in the question. Finally, don't post a wall of code for one error. Post an SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is an appropriate way to mark it in the question? I can't format the code block with bolding, etc.

Comment: Add a comment to the code. And strip out all the extraneous stuff. Read about SSCCE.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here. Here's one of them:

```
printf("%d", void PlayingDice(void));
```

Here, you're passing as the second parameter to `printf` the value `void PlayingDice(void)`. However, this isn't a value. `void PlayingDice(void)` is a function prototype that says "there is some function called `PlayingDice` that takes in nothing and returns nothing." It's not a value at all.  You probably meant to do something like this:

```
printf("%d", PlayingDice());
```

This actually calls `PlayingDice` and gets the return value. However, that *too* is problematic because the function returns `void`. You probably want to determine whether you want this function to return anything at all. If do, then make the return type `int`. If not, remove the `printf` entirely.

Similarly, this line is legal but almost certainly not what you want:

```
// Returns function to main
return main();
```

This does *not* return the function to `main`. Instead, it calls `main` again, waits for `main` to return a value, then returns the value that `main` produced. If you want to return back to `main`, just delete this statement. It's not doing anything.

Hope this helps!